# Abstract class method to deserialize string to inherited class properties

Tags: c#

Not sure if I worded the title correctly but I have the following class.

```
public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public bool PropertyB { get; set; }
    public int PropertyC { get; set; }
}
```

In the `BaseClass` I want to create 2 methods, one will serialize `ClassA` to a JSON string and the other will deserialize a JSON string to the properties in ClassA.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected string SerializeClass()
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
    }

    protected void DeserializeClass<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        // Obviously this isn't right but what do I do here?
        this = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonString);


        // The property jsonString will be generated from the
        // SerializeClass method and stored elsewhere.
        // This will result in properties in ClassA being populated.
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do instead of writing repetitive code on classes that will deserialize a JSON string and mapping each individual property, I am open for a way where my inherited base class has a function which will 'automap' as it where to the properties in the class which inherited base class.

Comment: Unfortunately pseudo-code you've posted does not explain what you want to achieve. Maybe try to explain it words or make code more real.

Comment: just notice that the use of abstract class here is worng, there is no need to use abstract class if you implements all the methods in the base class, Maybe you meant to use extension methods?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, sorry thought my intentions was self explanatory looking at the inherited class in `ClassA`. Added some extra details but I apologise it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a method that creates or overwrites `this` within the class.

You could set all of the *properties* but that would probably be more work than you're wanting.

You could use a static factory method:

```
protected static T DeserializeSettings<T>(string jsonString)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonString);
}
```

and then call it like a factory method:

```
ClassA a = BaseClass.DeserializeSettings<ClassA>(json);
```

Unfortunately there's not a way to infer genetic parameters just by the return type, so you'll have to add the generic parameter. You could add a shortcut to `ClassA`:

```
protected static ClassA DeserializeClass(string jsonString)
{
    return BaseClass.DeserializeClass<ClassA>(jsonString);
}
```

Then you could do:

```
ClassA a = ClassA.DeserializeSettings(json);
```

but you'd have to add the shortcut to every child class.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this:

```csharp
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : class
{
  abstract protected void CopyFrom(T? source);

  protected void Deserialize(string s)
  {
    CopyFrom(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(s));
  }
}

public class Derived : BaseClass<Derived>
{
  protected override void CopyFrom(Derived? source)
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

You can probably provide a default implementation for `CopyFrom` using AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

you can use extentions method with reflection to make it work exactly the way you wanted. I don't know reflection well enough, but it should work.

```
public static class Tools
{
    public static string SerializeClass<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
    }

    public static void DeserializeClass<T>(this T obj, string jsonString) 
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
        T temp = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonString);
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, prop.GetValue(temp));
        }
    }
}
```

than you can use it like that:

```
 ClassA classA = new ClassA()
 string jsonString = classA.SerializeClass()
 classA.DeserializeClass(jsonString);
```

just notice this code does not catch errors, so if you use it on a class that cannot be serialized, it will throw

Answer (score -1):

@codingStarter made a useful comment and don't know why I didn't think of it. Seems to be the most easiest method. Clearly on a brain block today.

```
public static class BaseClassExtensions
{
    public static string SerializeClass<T>(this T baseClass)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(baseClass);
    }

    public static T DeserializeClass<T>(this string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
    public bool PropertyB { get; set; }
    public int PropertyC { get; set; }
}
```

```
var myClass = new ClassA
{
    PropertyA = "ValueA",
    PropertyB = true,
    PropertyC = 1
};

var serialized = myClass.SerializeClass();

var deserialized = serialized.DeserializeClass<ClassA>();
```

Comment: Does this work? How does the compiler know what type to return from `DeserializedClass`? Wouldn;t you have to do `serialized.DeserializeClass<ClassA>();`?

Comment: there seems to be no way without actually using the generic parameter. still, extention method is a bit easier than static class to use. (maybe you can use reflections to solve this too, but it will be much more comlicated)

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the generic parameter when putting the code on here. Have amended the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).